# <CoreOS, cloud-config> How to 'Wait' until Docker Private Registry is ready?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, coreos

I am trying Docker on CoreOS on EC2.

What I want to do is:

- Run Docker private registry container
- Run other containers after pulling image from private registry

### Initial Configuration

My `cloud-config.yml` is like this:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start

    - name: fleet.service
      command: start

    - name: docker.service
      command: start
      drop-ins:
        - name: 50-insecure-registry.conf
          content: |
            [Service]
            Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="localhost:5000"'

    - name: private-docker-registry.service
      command: start
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=Docker Private Registry
       After=docker.service
       Requires=docker.service
       Requires=network-online.target
       After=network-online.target

       [Service]
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull registry:latest
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name private-docker-registry --privileged -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 -e AWS_BUCKET=bucket -e AWS_KEY=awskey -e AWS_SECRET=awssecret -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy -p 5000:5000 registry:latest

    - name: myservice.service
      command: start
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=My Service
       After=private-docker-registry.service
       Requires=private-docker-registry.service
       Requires=network-online.target
       After=network-online.target

       [Service]
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull localhost:5000/myservice:latest
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name myservice localhost:5000/myservice:latest
```

### myservice.service fails

Problem here is:

- myservice.service fails though private registry container is successfully running

As I login to the machine, it shows following message.

```
Failed Units: 1
  myservice.service
```

Command `journalctl -u private-docker-registry.service` shows this:

```
Jul 24 07:30:25 docker[830]: [2015-07-24 07:30:25 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
```

Command `journalctl -u myservice.service` shows following log.

```
Jul 24 07:30:25 systemd[1]: Starting My Service...
Jul 24 07:30:25 docker[836]: time="2015-07-24T07:30:25Z" level=fatal msg="Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connection refused"
Jul 24 07:30:25 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 24 07:30:25 systemd[1]: Failed to start My Service.
Jul 24 07:30:25 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 07:30:25 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However, I can run myservice container manually (after few minutes).

```
docker run --name myservice localhost:5000/myservice:latest
```

My assumption is:

- Pulling `myservice` image fails because `myservice.service` tries to pull `myservice` image **immediately** after private registry starts listening.

### Try & Error

Based on my assumption above, I added `wait-for-registry.service` which just wait 2 minutes after private registry starts.

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start

    - name: fleet.service
      command: start

    - name: docker.service
      command: start
      drop-ins:
        - name: 50-insecure-registry.conf
          content: |
            [Service]
            Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="localhost:5000"'

    - name: private-docker-registry.service
      command: start
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=Docker Private Registry
       After=docker.service
       Requires=docker.service
       Requires=network-online.target
       After=network-online.target

       [Service]
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull registry:latest
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name private-docker-registry --privileged -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3 -e AWS_BUCKET=bucket -e AWS_KEY=awskey -e AWS_SECRET=awssecret -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy -p 5000:5000 registry:latest

    - name: wait-for-registry.service
      command: start
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=Wait Until Private Registry is Ready
       After=private-docker-registry.service
       Requires=private-docker-registry.service

       [Service]
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 120

    - name: myservice.service
      command: start
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=My Service
       After=wait-for-registry.service
       After=private-docker-registry.service
       Requires=private-docker-registry.service
       Requires=network-online.target
       After=network-online.target

       [Service]
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull localhost:5000/myservice:latest
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name myservice localhost:5000/myservice:latest
```

But this causes same problem.

Command `journalctl -u private-docker-registry.service` shows this:

```
Jul 24 08:23:38 docker[838]: [2015-07-24 08:23:38 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
```

Command `journalctl -u wait-for-registry.service` shows this:

```
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: Started Wait Until Private Registry is Ready.
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: Starting Wait Until Private Registry is Ready...
```

Command `journalctl -u myservice.service` shows this:

```
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: Starting My Service...
Jul 24 08:23:37 docker[847]: time="2015-07-24T08:23:37Z" level=fatal msg="Error response from daemon: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://localhost:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: Failed to start My Service.
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 08:23:37 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It seems that `sleep` takes no effect.

### Question

**How can I make it wait until private registry will be available?**

Any hints or suggestions welcome!

Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

systemd unit files are tricky :-)

I think you just about have it. I am no expert, but, I will try to explain what I think is happening.

First, I think you might want to add a :

```
- name: wait-for-registry.service
  command: start
  runtime: true
  content: |
   [Unit]
   Description=Wait Until Private Registry is Ready
   After=private-docker-registry.service
   Requires=private-docker-registry.service

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 120
   RemainAfterExit=true
   Type=oneshot
```

The explaination would be that /usr/bin/sleep 120 *is* started.  Since it is started, the next Unit in the chain is started (your myservice.service). By changing it to a oneshot you have to wait until it is finished.  I am guessing here, though, because much of the unit stuff is trial and error for me.

I do have a similar construct in my unit files.  I don't think you really want 'sleep', that is a hack.  I think you really want to wait until port 5000 is answering, right?  If that is the case, you can replace the sleep with:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /opt/bin/waiter.sh
```

Then, towards the top of the cloud-config:

```
write_files:
  - path: /opt/bin/waiter.sh
    permissions: 0755
    owner: root
    content: |
      #! /usr/bin/bash
      until curl -s http://127.0.0.1:5000/; do echo waiting waiter.sh; sleep 2; done
```

Or something similar.  Wait until there is something at that port before continuing.

-g

Comment: This really helped! I appreciate you, @Greg:-)